# combine image and audio ffmpeg xampp php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, xampp

I have ffmpeg installed in my xampp.  I'm trying combine one image file with one audio file to produce one video file using a php script.  However, no file is produced.  I've tried:

```
<?php

$ffmpegcmd = "ffmpeg -loop 1 -i C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.png -i C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage \ -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.mp4";

shell_exec($ffmpegcmd);  

?>
```

and

```
<?php

shell_exec("ffmpeg -loop 1 -i C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.png -i C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage \ -c:a aac -strict  experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.mp4");

?>
```

and

```
<?php

shell_exec("C:\xampp\php\ext\ffmpeg -loop 1 -i C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.png -i C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage \ -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.mp4");

?>
```

Comment: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)! You should get rid of PHP, make the command line working fine from shell and only then wrap the solution within `<?php`.

Comment: Good advice to test with command line first.  The above script had an extra "\" that was messing things up and the output mp4 was longer than the original audio.  I found a ffmpeg script that worked better:  ffmpeg -loop 1 -i dog.jpg -i dog.wav -shortest -acodec copy -f mov dog.mp4  however, it still doesn't work with shell_exec() in a php script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with slashes inside your double-quoted string. PHP threats those as command sequences (e.g. `\n` states for carriage return etc.)

You have two possibilities: either escape slashes with [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php):

```
<?php
  shell_exec( addslashes( '$ffmpegcmd = "ffmpeg -loop 1 -i C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.png -i C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage \ -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.mp4'; ) );
?>
```

Comment: I tried the single quotes and it didn't work.  I don't really understand how to use addslashes.  Do I just insert the string where you put "cmd" after the "$"?

Comment: I provided a link to `addslashes` description. `$cmd` is for your command. You should substitute it with your command in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but neither the single quotes or the addslashes is working.  I even added the line in a php code that is working and I'm not getting any error messages.  It just seems to skip over the shell_exec line.  Maybe it has something to do with xammp.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a script that works, but I'm a bit confused about what's going on.  This script references the ffmpeg.exe file.  But shouldn't the script be able to run on the php_ffmpeg.dll when I'm using xampp?  In fact, I removed the php_ffmpeg.dll and ran the script and it still worked.  What was the point then of even installing the .dll?  And will this script work when I use it on a real server?

Here's the script that works, with or without the .dll:

```
<?php

shell_exec('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -i "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.jpg" -i "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.wav" -shortest -acodec copy -f mov C:\xampp\htdocs\testingffmpeg\dog.mp4');

?>
```